# Kivy on Raspberry Pi: Mouse cursor not showing

Tags: python, gui

I'm running kivy on a Raspberry Pi. I accepted that apparently you can't get around the fullscreen, but I can't get the cursor to show either. I tried by adding

```
touchring = show_cursor=true
```

to the [modules]-section of config.ini (in my home directory and the root directory), but it's not working. In the [graphics]-section

```
show_cursor = 1
```

is set as well, but nothing changes. Somebody know another solution?

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

For others, who might like me be bloody beginners on Linux/Pi/Python, and can't find the `cursor.py` file:

To simply add a cursor in your kivy-apps, add this to the end of the `config.ini` in `~./.kivy` (below the [modules] thingy):

```
cursor=1
```

There's obviously many different options you can additionally change, like the cursortexture and whatnot. But for me it was sufficient to finally see any cursor at all, so i didn't really bother about those other options.

If you can't find the `config.ini` file run the following code:

```
import kivy

print(kivy.kivy_home_dir)
```